# How to exclude recursive module dependencies?

Tags: 7, .info

Is there a way to exclude dependencies of dependencies? For example:
**my_module.info** contains
`dependencies[] = views`

`dependencies[] = ctools`

**my_sub_module.info** contains

`dependencies[] = my_module`

On the module display page my_sub_modue will have my_module, views and ctools as dependencies. I know this is the desired outcome in 99% of all situations but I was curious to know if there were a way to have only my_module (or items explicitly stated in the info file) as the dependency for my_sub_module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best is have always in mind solid and stable solution.

If you have this problem you should change your design, not your code.

Your module should have a display, and your submodule should have a display who modifies your module's display.

Comment: To help clarify my question, is there a way to have "items explicitly stated in the info file" as the dependencies instead of them being recursively resolved? The specific reason for this is although I could accomplish the same with `module_exists` or `function_exists` and provide a drupal_set_message, I would like to use drupal's established way of displaying these dependencies on the modules page instead of making my own.

Comment: Thanks for the typos, SOLID isn't really a typo are five principles of software design.